# Hashmap to Recycler view Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, linkedhashmap

I want to render Recyclerview based on a hashmap which contains `LinkedHashMap<String, MutableList<CustonClass>>`.

I am able to add multiple view holders in Adapter.
But unable to track one layout for a hashmap-key for value.

please suggest.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: That will be a `SectionedRecyclerView`  similar to `ExpandableListView` where hashmap key will represent a group and value will be the items under this group . Where Exactly you are stuck in this ? There r multiple implementation available for `SectionedRecyclerView` on Git .

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use a nested recycler view @ADM

Comment: That data will draw a nested one anyway . you need add the code with question what you already have . Also add the expected result arrangement if u can maybe an an image.